# Getting a null when trying to return File( ) in my controller c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> So i am getting a null when trying to return a file and don't know how to get the data from my method.

```
public ActionResult ExportFile(string[] response)
    {


        ClientStatement_Inventory theStatementPath = new ClientStatement_Inventory();
        var thePath = theStatementPath.statementPath;



        DBQueries getyears = new DBQueries();
        getyears.GetSpecificYears(response);

        var cd = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileNameStar = theStatementPath.statementPath
        };


        return File(theStatementPath.statementPath, theStatementPath.statementYear);
        //return File(thePath, "appliction/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(response.ToString()));
```

> Here is my method in a different class where i am trying to get the data:

```
public class DBQueries 
{
    // Access Connection String
    //string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["..."].ConnectionString;

    public List<string> GetSpecificYears(string[] response)
    {

        // Acquiring SqlConnection as a resource
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("..."))
        {
        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

            //Open Connection
            con.Open();

            if (response != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (response[i] == "2019")
                    {

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select statementPath from ClientStatement_Inventory where statementYear = '" + response[i] + "';", con))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {

                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    paths.Add(reader.GetString(0));

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }
            return paths;
        }
    }

}
```

> I am able to get the file path from this sql query but how can i pass that to my controller and download the file(s)?

Comment: what's the meaning of "download"? get url from db then download to your server, or return a file result to the client and trigger a download event?

Comment: So I have a db with the filepath saved in a row called statementPath. In my query I am grabbing the file path according to what year the user selects on the frontend. I then am returning the end result of all file paths with return paths to my controller. After that I need those files to be downloaded. Make sense? Sorry for the unclear question. And I know my controller isn't even close to what I need to do. I actually need to zip all of the files and download them.